# How to connect JavaScript to Python script with Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web-frameworks

I created a website with HTML/CSS. I also used Javascript for events (click on button, ...).

Now I want to connect a Python script with it and more importantly, return the results from my Python functions to my website and display (use) them there.

Consider something like this: I have a website with an input field and a button. If you click on the button, a Python script should run which returns if the input is an odd or even number (of course you don't need Python for this specific case, but that's what I want to do).

From my research I believe Flask is the library to be used for this, but I really don't know how to do it. I found very few examples. I would really appreciate if someone could implement the above example or tell me how to do it exactly.

I know there are already some questions about that concept here online, but as I said, with very few examples.

Comment: The Flask docs now has a full example: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really appreciate time spent [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59976185/2745495). But the answer did not help me in the way I needed it. At that point I had no clue what to do, but since thenbI figured it out some time ago and I thought I should share my solution here:

That's app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/stick', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stick():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form['string1'] + request.form['string2']
        return render_template('index.html', result=result)
    else:   
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And that's index.html (put in the folder **templates**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3> Stick two strings </h3>
    <form action="{{ url_for('stick') }}" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="string1">
            <input type="text" name="string2">
            <input type="submit" value="Go!">
            <p id="result"></p>
    </form>
<script>

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "{{result}}"

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the terminal, type in *python app.py* and it should work.

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure as well as the codes in a **github repo** or here? I am also facing the issue as like as you but cannot get rid of the problem. My goal is to run a Python Script from the Client side and I am thinking to use **Flask** as a interim medium.

Apart from this, you have written to write on the terminal `python stackpy.py`. Is it correct or it will be `python app.py`?

Comment: @user10634362 if you wanted to run python on the cilentside, then the user has to install Python!  If you wanted to run random code on the server-side as submitted by the cilent. I think that represents a problem in your design.  Python can do anything including delete files.  And I'm no expert on how to limit what operations your flask server can do.

Answer (score 12):

You're right about Flask being a good solution for this and there are examples and tutorials everywhere. If what you want is just to run a specific function on a button press and get something back in javascript, I've put a quick example is below.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# Display your index page
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# A function to add two numbers
@app.route("/add")
def add():
    a = request.args.get('a')
    b = request.args.get('b')
    return jsonify({"result": a+b})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

This can then be run with `python app.py` and make sure your index.html is in the same directory. Then you should be able to go to http://127.0.0.1/ and see your page load.

This implements a function which adds two numbers, this can be called in your javascript by calling http://127.0.0.1/add?a=10&b=20. This should then return `{"result": 30}`.

You can grab this in your javascript using the code below and place this code in your buttons on click callback.

```
let first = 10;
let second = 20;
fetch('http://127.0.0.1/add?a='+first+'&b='+second)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    console.log("When I add "+first+" and "+second+" I get: " + myJson.result);
  });
```

This should be the barebone basics, but once you can submit data to Flask and get data back, you now have an interface to run things in Python.

Edit: Full Front-end example

https://jsfiddle.net/4bv805L6/

Comment: much appreciated! However could you be more precise about he index.html file? 
I have somewhat of an hard time following the tutorials as they are not very clear. I need one complete example where I don`t need do add anything in order to understand working with flask.
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/4bv805L6/ this will work when flask isn't running for a demo, but once flask is running, make sure you remove lines 13-16 so you can actually see flasks response.

Comment: Again, thank you for your time spent! But i am even more confused now as i don`t see any flask command in your code example ...

Comment: Running "python app.py" from the directory of these files will start the application. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is awesome.  Thank you for your coding expertise.  Upvoted!